# What episode of Deep Space 9 came before Star Trek: Insurrection?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-insurrection

I am trying to work out when Worf could have been away long enough in between episodes to have been on the Enterprise E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by release order, it was [Covenant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708520/). It aired 11/25/98, *Insurrection* released 12/11/98, and [It's Only a Paper Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708562/?ref_=tt_ep_nx) aired 12/30/98

Comment: This makes sense. In the movie, it was mentioned that Worf was on leave from DS9. In the episode "It's Only a Paper Moon" the crew seemed to be taking a break from the war (perhaps because of the events in "The Siege of AR-558", just 2 episodes before that) and Worf didn't appear in that episode.

Comment: While the Star Trek episodes are generally aired in order in-universe, the release date of Insurrection doesn't necessarily mean it falls within the same timeline as the currently airing episodes. A better check would be to compare the star dates.

Comment: @Xantec There was no stardate mentioned in Insurrection, so that won't work here. But I found an entire timeline on http://thestartrekchronologyproject.blogspot.nl/2009/09/step-1.html They actually placed the movie just after the final episode of DS9. But they mention that the other episode is also a possibility.